# Difference between JpaSort vs Sort

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sorting, jpa

I have seen that when using Spring Boot there are JpaSort as well as Sort available for sorting and using in pagination. I have tried to figure out the difference between these two, but could not find much information regarding that.

Can someone tell me the difference between these two from a performance perspective as well as implementation perspective?

Comment: Well `JpaSort` is a subclass of (i.e. extends) `Sort`.  `JpaSort` offers some helper methods for sorting, such as `#unsafe()` which at times are useful.  Your best bet would be to check the documentation to see all the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1) What is *JPA Metamodel*?**

> Often, when we write a criteria query, we need to reference entity
> classes and their attributes. Now, one of the ways of doing this is to
> provide the attributes' names as strings. But, this has several
> downsides. The JPA Metamodel was introduced by the community to avoid
> these drawbacks and provide static access to the metadata of the
> managed entity classes. For one, we have to look up the names of
> entity attributes. And, in case **a column name is changed later** in the
> project lifecycle, we have to **refactor each query** where the name is
> being used.

source https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries-metamodel#prerequisites

**(2) Inheritance between `JpaSort` and `Sort`**

```java
public class JpaSort extends Sort
```

**(3) Authoritative definitions.**

`Sort` Sort option for queries. You have to provide at least a list of properties to sort for that must not include null or empty strings. The direction defaults to `DEFAULT_DIRECTION`.

`JpaSort` Sort option for queries that wraps **JPA meta-model Attributes** for sorting.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/JpaSort.html

Let's see example

```java
Page<Product> allProductsSortedByName = productRepository.findAll(Sort.by("name"));
Order order1 = new Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "published");
```

and

```java
List<Employee> list = repo.findByDepartment("Sales", JpaSort.unsafe("LENGTH(name)", "salary"));
```

**(4) Conclusion:** `JpaSort` support *JPA meta-model Attributes* what `Sort` does not support.

Comment: Could you add a bit more about the `JpaSort.unsafe` . Is there any speciality about it.

Comment: likes unchecked exception